# Type Any has no subscript members json Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, swift3

I have this code:

```
let subjectAbbreviation = JSON?["data"]??["subject"]??["abbr"] as? String
```

Swift 3 complains:

> Type Any has no subscript members

How would I unwrap this? I know I can use `(JSON as? AnyObject)` seems kind of messy though.

Comment: Refer these links http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=type+any+has+no+subscript+members

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to specify the type of your json to `[String: Any]` so try like this.

```
if let jsondata = json as? [String: Any], let data = jsondata["data"] as? [String: Any], let subject = data["subject"] as? [String: Any], let addr = subject["subject"] as? String {
    print(addr)
}
```