# How can I get value of the print out 'Json' content in swift 5?

Tags: json, parsing, swift5

`print(json)` output is below.

```
{response = { success = 1; successmsg = "Successful Connection"; };}
```

How can I get value of "success" or "successmsg"?
I am getting the error "Type 'Any' has no subscript members" when I use line below in Swift 5.

`let response = json["response"]` as? [String: Any]

I would be grateful for any progress.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [decode Json string to class object Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53367491/decode-json-string-to-class-object-swift)

Comment: https://forums.swift.org/t/type-any-has-no-subscript-members-error-in-swift-4

Comment: and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39740847/type-any-has-no-subscript-members-json-swift-3